# android Searchable dictionary results are not being shown in global search

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have tried to implement the searchable dictionary sample app.
Everything seems to be working except when I try to pull the results from global search.
I have tried to follow everything that has been described in the docs too.

My searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/search_label"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
        android:searchSuggestAuthority="sd2.com.achie.DictionaryProvider"
        android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://sd2.com.achie.DictionaryProvider/dictionary"
        android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
        android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
        android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
        >
 </searchable>
```

And the authorities, mime types

```
public static String AUTHORITY = "sd2.com.achie.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +"/vnd.sd2.com.achie";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +"/vnd.sd2.com.achie";
```

My Manifest is

```
    <!-- Receives the search request. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <!-- No category needed, because the Intent will specify this class component-->
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- Points to searchable meta data. -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable" />            

</activity>
<!-- Displays the definition of a word. -->
<activity android:name=".WordActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

<!-- Provides search suggestions for words and their definitions. -->
<provider android:name=".DictionaryProvider"
          android:authorities="sd2.com.achie.DictionaryProvider" />

<!-- Points to searchable activity so the whole app can invoke search. -->
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
           android:value=".SearchableDictionary" />
```

What might be the problem?

Thank you,
Achie

Comment: What happens when you try to pull the results from global search?

Comment: It does not show the results from dictionary. I could not see where I am going wrong I can post the entire code somewhere if you want to check

Comment: Where is the bit of code that is trying to pull something from the global search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything was fine but I did not explicitly configure the search settings to show the searchable dictionary in search results. Once I added that, everything worked fine.